# environment variable .. why is that?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, environment-variables

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I want to code with DLL files.

I adjusted the system environment Path, like `C:~~`, but execute file can't find DLL files. So I moved the DLL files to `c:windows\system32`. Then I can use it.

Why can't that find DLL files? I want to know how the computer loads DLL files by using the system environment path.

My path setting is:

```
%OPENCV_DIR%\bin
```

(there are DLL files in bin folder)

```
(OPENCV_DIR = C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10)
```

and i'm testing Opencv

Comment: You cannot reference other environment variables in the PATH environment variable.  Forgetting to log-out and logging back in is a common mistake.  Don't use PATH, copy the DLLs into the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx